# Applying Weak Energy Condition for a specific energy-momentum tensor

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

So, I have a particular energy-momentum tensor, for a specific line element, and I want to check if this obeys the weak energy condition ($T_{ \mu \nu} U^\mu U^\nu \geq 0$ where $U^\mu$ and $U^\nu$ are timelike vector fields). I guess I might just say that $\rho = T_{00} \geq 0$ which is a straightforward calculation for a given locally inertial frame. But how can I apply WEC independently of coordinate system? How should I write the vector fields $U^\mu$ and $U^\nu$?